# How to build an J2EE application with docker

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, docker, devops

I have always been confused with this question.From my point of view, docker is been used to wrap the application inside it for developing(make a volume), testing and deploying. My question is, building a J2EE using maven need to `mvn clean & mvn package` and then dump the war file into the tomcat webapp. Is there a more convenient way to achieve this like once I change the code, then the result will automatically show up when I access the ip of the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use volume binding for what you want. you can achieve it like this `docker run -d -v $(pwd):/code-directory` `$(pwd)` is your local directory.

**Take note:** This is only recommended on local environment

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the quick reply. When we are building software with maven, we have to package the code into some jar or war. This could take a long time to see the result. I am wondering if there is a way to see the effect right away by using docker in this scenario?

Comment: I'm not a Maven person so I can not really relate. But I can suggest for you guys to look for existing images that can help you. I did a quick research and I can see that spotify made their own `docker-maven-image` here https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin. Maybe you can take a look at that

Comment: Thanks so much for your patient reply. I will check that out!

Comment: I would appreciate if you can vote for my answer in return :)